# mongoose | batch insert and update if already exists

Tags: node.js, mongoose

I have the following Schema

```
const domain = new Schema({
   created: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
   last_update: { type: Date, default: Date.now },
   domain: String,
});
```

index in schema is `domain`.

I want to do batch insert for this collection.

but if a document exist I only want it to be updated (and not double inserted)

for example: if the collection has the following domains:

```
gmail.com, yahoo.com, msn.com
```

And i want to insert and update the following data:

```
let data = [{domain:"gmail.com", test: true}, {domain:"fake.com", test: false}]
```

I expect the collection to add `fake.com` and to update `gmail.com`

what is the correct way to do so?

Answer (score 1):

You use [db.collection.update()](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.update/) with the `upsert` option:

> Upsert: If set to true, creates a new document when no
>   document matches the query criteria. The default value is false, which
>   does not insert a new document when no match is found.

```
Domains.update( // Or db.domains with mongodb directly
   {
      domain: 'www.something.com'
   },
   {
      domain: 'www.something.com'
   },
   {
     upsert: true
   }
)
```

If you're targeting multiple documents by the unique domain key, I'm not aware that there is a way to do it in a single batch command.

Comment: how do I update each domain with it's on data on a batch operation? what should be the query?

Comment: If you don't want to overwrite all the data in the document, use `{ $set: { domain: '...', anotherProp: '...' }}` for second param as far as I know, this should keep existing properties not listed there. To do this in a batch I'm not sure there is another way other than doing it in a loop

Comment: i want to override all the data in the document. but i'm not sure what is the proper query i need to for the UPDATE function. i want each domain to be updated with it's domain data

Answer (score 0):

for insert and update if already exists. here is my solution-

```
let addSurveyQuestion = [];
    fields.forEach(async (item) => {
      addSurveyQuestion.push({
        updateOne: {
          filter: { slug: item.cid },
          update: {
            title: item.label,
            survey_id,
            image: item.image ? item.image : null,
            description: item.field_options.description,
            options: optionData,
            other_option: item.field_options.include_other_option
              ? item.field_options.include_other_option
              : null,
            type: item.field_type,
            slug: item.cid,
            required: item.required,
          },
          upsert: true,
        },
      });
      await SurveyQuestion.bulkWrite(addSurveyQuestion);
```